# Issues with constants in static block java

Tags: java, exception, static

I have two questions regarding the static block and Constants with below code.

1. Constant (or even simple Static variable) cannot be directly referrenced from static block. It gives error saying "Cannot reference a field before it is defined". But it is ok when accessing through a static method.
2. If I assign a value to a constant in static block's catch as mentioned below it gives error saying "The final field NAME may already have been assigned". But if asigning in catch it gives error saying "The blank final field NAME may not have been initialized".

I want to know why is it bahaving like this?

**Code :**

```
public class TestStaticblock {

    static{
        try {
//          NAME = dummyStringValue() + NAME_APPENDER; // Cannot reference a field before it is defined
//          NAME = dummyStringValue() + getNameAppender(); // This is OK

            NAME = dummyStringValue();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            NAME = null; // The final field NAME may already have been assigned
        }
    }

    private static String dummyStringValue() throws Exception{
        return "dummy";
    }

    private static String getNameAppender() throws Exception{
        return NAME_APPENDER;
    }

    private static final String NAME; // If I comment Catch it says "The blank final field NAME may not have been initialized"
    private static  String NAME_APPENDER = "appender";

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only assign to `NAME` once (because it is `final`). Assign the result to a temporary variable, and then assign to `NAME` (and don't silently swallow `Exception`s). Something like,

```
static {
    String temp = null;
    try {
        temp = dummyStringValue();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    NAME = temp;
}
```

The reason you can't assign `NAME` the way your are currently is because the compiler performs [static program analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_program_analysis) (specifically, the [data-flow analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data-flow_analysis)) and that detects that there is a possible code path where NAME is not assigned. And because NAME is `final`, that is a compilation error.

Comment: Yes. I also have managed it by taking the exception handling and initialization to another static method and assign the value to NAME by taken the return value of that static method. But I want to know why is this behaving like this? If it is assigned only once (since it is saying "The final field NAME may already have been assigned" in catch) why it is saying "The blank final field NAME may not have been initialized" when I comment the catch? And do you have any idea on my first question? Thank you for the answer.

Comment: This is a nice conversation. But then why it is not allowing me to assign the value in catch?

Comment: Because the `try` might not throw an exception (data-flow analysis still). The compiler won't examine the method body to determine that it **always** throws an `Exception` (exceptions are intended to be *exceptional*).

Comment: Oh! I missed your edit to the previous comment when I replied. Now I have something to study in there-data flow analysis. Thank you for the valuable reference. Do you have an idea on my question number 1.

Comment: You can use `NAME` **after** `NAME = temp` in the `static` block above.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I don't think this is about the method body. The point is that in the line `NAME = dummyStringValue();`, the exception can only occur inside `dummyStringValue()` not from the assignment. So inside the `catch` block it is completely impossible that `NAME` will already have been assigned no matter how `dummyStringValue()` is written. I guess they just didn't want to make the rules too complicated.

Comment: @PaulBoddington Correct, but if the method throws an exception then `NAME` wouldn't have been assigned. What if it set two `static` fields? Which of the two were assigned before the `Exception`? How would you handle it then?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch You can't assign values to static final fields in static methods at all, only in static initialisers or at the point of declaration. I think that's the point the OP is getting at.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this would be of assistance to those looking for something similar.

There is a little-known feature of Java (discussed in JavaSpecialists [Throwing Exceptions from Fields](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue208.html) that if you wish to initialise a `final` **instance variable** (i.e. **NOT** a `static`) to the result of a method call that **throws an exception** then you can avoid the obvious error by adding a constructor that throws the exception.
Note that this solution **only works for non-statics** (not what you are observing).

```
public class TestStaticblock {

    private final String NAME = dummyStringValue();

    // Adding this removes the "unreported Exception" above.
    public TestStaticblock() throws Exception {
    }

    private static String dummyStringValue() throws Exception {
        return "dummy";
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok OldCurmudgeon. Nice tips. There also I need to study a bit. It will be very valuable. Thank you!.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use a `static final` field in a static block before it has been assigned, yet you can access it just by calling a method.

For example, this code prints `null FOO`:

```
public class Main {

    static final String FOO;

    static {
        foo();
        FOO = "FOOFOO".substring(0, 3);
        foo();
    }

    static void foo() {
        System.out.println(FOO);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {}
}
```

This is undeniably odd, but I guess it would have made the language considerably more complicated to make things such as this impossible.

As for your second question, this doesn't compile.

```
static{
    try {
        NAME = dummyStringValue();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        NAME = null; // The final field NAME may already have been assigned
    }
}
```

This is also odd. If an exception is thrown it can only have occurred inside the method `dummyStringValue()`. Since you can't assign values to `final` fields inside a method, it is completely impossible for the `NAME` variable to have already been assigned in the `catch` block. Therefore there is no possible code path where `NAME` is not assigned. You'd think it ought to work in the same way as

```
static{
    if (someCondition()) {
        NAME = dummyStringValue();
    } else {
        NAME = null;
    }
}
```

which compiles fine.

I guess the reason is again that it would have made the language much more complicated to allow this. There is no great benefit to allowing it as you can just use a method or a `temp` variable as indicated in the other answers. Exceptions just are more complicated than `if` statements - they can act almost like a `goto`. A good point was made by @ElliottFrisch in the comments. What about something like this:

```
static{
    try {
        NAME1 = dummyStringValue1();
        NAME2 = dummyStringValue2();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Has NAME1 been assigned here?
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Paul. There are nice points in your answer as well as in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

My strong personal preference is to use methods instead of static initializer blocks which initializer a single variable:

```
private static final String NAME = getName();

private static String getName() {
  try {
    return something();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

1. You don't get issues like the one you have described.
2. You can only calculate one field value, so you are not tempted to throw lots of things into the same block.
3. You can re-invoke a method to test it.

Comment: Ok Andy. Thank you very much for the out-side-of the box answer. Meantime  I'm interesting on knowing why is it behaving like that. I got some cool tips (data-flow analysis, static analysis etc) with the conversation with Elliot. By the way, do you have an idea on Question number 1?